# p:commandButton id ignored

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having a hard time with the id of a primefaces commandButton.
Here is the code:

```
<p:commandButton 
    title="Compute Distances" icon="ui-icon-refresh"
    id="computeDistance"
    actionListener="#{distances.compute()}"
    update="@(:input)"/>
```

When the whole page gets displayed, the id that is defined in this code seems to be ignored: when looking at the html, the button's id is j_idt815.
But the button seems to work correctly: the actionListener method is called.

In the form, there is a text field which generates an ajax event on blur. This event updates allmost all components of the form, including the command button (but it doesn't do any modification on the button).
When leaving this text field, the ajax event is sent, and after the update, the command button is exactly the same as before, except that it now has the id that I have defined (computeDistance), instead of a generated id!
And from this point, the button stops working: when I click it, the actionListener method is not called (I have set a breakpoint at the beginning of this method).

If I don't set the id of the button, then it works fine: even after the text field has triggered the event, clicking the button always calls the actionListener.

I would expect that if the id is defined, it's always this one that is in the generated html, not a generated id of the form j_idtxxx. Am I correct?

By the way, I'm using primefaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.10
It looks to me like a primefaces/mojarra bug, but I haven't found notes of this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inspect `<p:commandButton/>` using [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), and check the `id`, if it displays id correctly or not.

Comment: That's what I'm doing: the values that I have indicated are those found in chrome developer tools (firebug equivalent).

Comment: Why you are using older version. Use latest version of [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/downloads).

Comment: We want to avoid regressions and we do not have time to retest the whole application.